# I'm getting Error as : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; How can i overcome with this one

Tags: java, jdbc

*I'm just trying to develop the simple web application where we can write notes as depicted in figure below:*

[image]

when  i add any text inside **Add Your Notes** and  i click on the button "**Add Notes**" to submit, it doesn't store in database.

*I have created a database name "**Enote**" and table name="**post**" as shown below:
[image]

*Sql Query is*

[image]

*Following is the code of jsp:*

**addNotes.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Notes</title>
<%@include file="all_component/allcss.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<%@include file="all_component/navbar.jsp" %>
<h1 class="text-center">Add Your Notes</h1>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<form action="AddNotesServlet" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  
  <%
     UserDetails us=(UserDetails)session.getAttribute("userD");
  
  %>


    <input type="hidden" value="<%=us.getId()%>" name="uid">  
  
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="title" required="required">
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Content</label>
         <textarea rows="9" cols="" class="form-control" name="content" required="required"></textarea>
     </div>
  
<div class="container text-center">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Notes</button>

</div>
</form>

</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Post.java*

```
package com.User;
import java.util.Date;
public class Post 
{
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Date pdate;
    private UserDetails user;
    public Post(int id, String title, String content, Date pdate, UserDetails user) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.pdate = pdate;
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Post() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public Date getPdate() {
        return pdate;
    }
    public void setPdate(Date pdate) {
        this.pdate = pdate;
    }
    public UserDetails getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(UserDetails user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
}
```

*PostDAO.java*

```
package com.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class PostDAO 

{
    private Connection con;

    public PostDAO(Connection con) {
        super();
        this.con = con;
    }
        
    public boolean AddNotes(String ti, String co,int ui)
    {
        boolean f=false;
        try
        {
            String qu="insert into post(title,content,uid) values=(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(qu);
            ps.setString(1, ti);
            ps.setString(2, co);
            ps.setInt(3, ui);
            
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i==1)
            {
                f=true; 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        return f;
        
    }
    
}
```

*AddNotesServlet.java*

```
package com.Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.DAO.PostDAO;
import com.DB.DBConnect;

@WebServlet("/AddNotesServlet")
public class AddNotesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        int uid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uid"));
        String title=request.getParameter("title");
        String content=request.getParameter("content");
        
        PostDAO dao =new PostDAO(DBConnect.getConn());
        boolean f= dao.AddNotes(title, content, uid);
        if (f)
        {
            System.out.println("data insert successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("data not inserted");
        }
    }

}
```

*Following is the error when i execute the code which gives output in console  that **data is not inserted**:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's `INSERT INTO post (title, content, uid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` - you tossed an `=` sign between `VALUES` and the question marks, which is an SQL syntax error. Which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error means your query is incorrect format, try looking for correct format in sql documentaion. Here's the correct syntax

`INSERT INTO products (name, price, product_no) VALUES ('Cheese', 9.99, 1);`

Documentation link - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/dml-insert.html